# What is correct form of writing: "users names" or "user names"?

Tags: grammar, programming

Let me ask you a question which I've derived from my programming practice:

Let's assume, I have a number of users represented by their names: John, Pete, Stanislaw, Marc, ...

What words should I use to name such collection of names of users: **user names**, or **users names**?

Thanks.

---

To provide more context, here is similar example for programmers:

JSON of objects: `[{"id": 1, ...}, {"id": 2, ...}, {"id": 3, ...}, ...]`

How should I name a variable representing a collection of identificators (ids) of given objects:

```
var objectIds; // or
var objectsIds;

var objectIdentificators; // or
var objectsIdentificators;
```

?

Comment: Please, read carefully, what I am asking. It is not a duplicate!

Comment: When you know the correct spelling is **username**, then the plural form would be **usernames**.

Comment: My question is not only about a spelling of the word __username__, but rather about a shorter form of writing: the names of the users - that is what I intend to make the name of my collection to represent - so it's meaning is wider than just "usernames". Am I clear?

Comment: This is not a question about English language or usage, it is a question about variable naming. You can name your variables anything you like. But if you want your name to represent an English phrase, then English plural NP show the plural form in the head (final) word and hardly ever in any other word.

Comment: @ColinFine, so the both forms are correct then? I just want to know if there is a rule for this case. Please see how I've updated my programmatic example: __objectIdentificators__ or __objectsIdentificators__?

Comment: Well, I'm not a programmer! It appears so to me.

Comment: @Susan, I've read your answer, but it does not explain me, why "both forms are not correct". You will make me happy, if you extend your answer with an explanation of __why__ they are not correct. Thanks!

Comment: Isn't this because it is the concatenation of words that make you feel these forms malformed? It is OK for programming languages to concatenate words.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> What words should I use to name such collection of names of users: user names, or users names?

In the second example, users names sounds like *user's names*. You are already pluralizing **names**; I believe you are modifying *names* with the adjective *user*.

Using another adjective-noun pair might help clarify the situation:

sentence structures vs. sentenses structures

The latter is very odd. *Structures* is being modified by *sentence*. That is enough information.

Edited by request: There is too much information imparted in the second example.  The thing, the noun, we want to emphasize is the head (or final) word: *structures*. The word *sentence* here is an adjective. It doesn't need to be plural.

Again, if we were writing about a more than one horse farm, we would say horse **farms** to indicate that the most important word (which is *farm*) is plural. It would just confuse things to say **horses** *farms*. It would only make sense if the farms belonged to the **all** of the horses. Obviously they do not, or there would be an apostrophe: *horses**'***  *farms*.

Your 'names' do not belong to all of the users collectively. Each has his own user name. Together , they are **user names**.

Comment: Thanks for additional clarification. I've read your edits!

Comment: Sorry for perseverance. The last question: is the form __objects identificators__ would be incorrect if I want to emphasize/indicate the fact that a collection I'am dealing with is a collection of identificators of __distinct objects__?!

Comment: No. _Objects identificators_ would probably never be written by a native English speaker. As I said in another comment, we almost always pluralise only the last word in a noun phrase. But if pushed, I would interpret as negating the outermost verb, so "or did not want".There's another reason why a native English speaker is unlikely to write this: we would use _identifiers_ not _identificators_. So I would use _objectIdentifiers_ (or _objectIds_). But again, it's your program, so you can call your variables anything you wish.

Comment: Great! Thanks for clarification! And sorry for this my russian-based "identificator" - I've just forgot to substitute it with correct "identifier". I will accept Susan's answer as correct.

Comment: By the way, I've asked this question because of I thought there will be a similarity beetween english and russian languages in this aspect: in russian language the correct form of writing this would be exactly: plural + plural (not singular + plural). Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

Please allow me to answer this question by quoting from a grammar book: *Practical English Usage* by Michael Swan. According to **531 singular** and **plural** (9): noun + noun:

> **531.1 first noun singular: shoe shop**
>   In **noun** + **noun** structures, the first noun is normally singular in form even if it has a plural meaning.
>     *a **shoe** shop* (= a shop that sells shoes)
>     *a **toothbrush*** (= a brush for teeth)
>     ***trouser*** pockets (= pockets in trousers)
>     *a **ticket** office* (= an office that sells tickets)
>
> **531.2 exceptions**
>   Some nouns are plural in this structure. These include nouns which have no singular form (like *clothes*), nouns which are not used in the singular with the same meaning (like *customs*), and some nouns which are more often used in the plural than in the singular (like *savings*). In some cases, e.g. *antique(s)*, *drug(s)*, usage is divided, and both singular and plural forms are found. In general, plurals are becoming more common in this structure. Examples: [...]
>
> Note also that singular nouns ending in *-ics* can be used before other nouns.
>     ***athletics*** training
>     *an **economics** degree*
>
> We use the plurals men and women to modify plural nouns when they have a 'subject' meaning; *man* and *woman* are used to express an 'object' meaning. Compare:
>   - ***men*** drivers (= men who drive)
>     ***women*** pilots (= women who fly planes)
>   - ***man***-eaters (= lions or tigers that eat people)
>     ***woman***-haters (= people who hate women)

The last four examples are especially helpful: *user* in *username* is used to express an 'object' meaning. A *username* means a name of a user, not a user who names something.

Comment: I wish I could have an option to accept the both of the answers.