# Events calendar/activities calendar or event calendar/activity calendar?

Tags: phrases

Which is correct (or more commonly-used) Events calendar/activities calendar or event calendar/activity calendar?

Thanks!

Comment: Related: *[What is correct form of writing: “users names” or “user names”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/143103)* and *[Should a list of tokens be called a “token list” or a “tokens list”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/59059)* among many others.

Answer (score 0):

**Calendar of Events** is current usage.  Look at the Ngram below and compare.[image]